# Derivative of an improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, improper-integrals

Let $f(x) = \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-xt}}{t^2}dt$, $x \in (0,\infty)$. Show that $f(x)$ is differentiable in $(0,\infty)$ and find its derivative.

I don't know what direction I have to think to solve this. I think Leibniz rule of integration can be used but I am not able to apply that even.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you heard some thing like "Leibniz rule", or "differentiation under integral sign" ?

Comment: Yes and about that, I have mentioned it above. I being little poor while dealing with integrals, not able to use it properly. And what about the part where we have to justify it's derivability?

Answer (score 0):

With $C^1$ nature of your function (Leibniz) you use this theorem

Hypothesis:

1) Your function in terms of $x$ is $C^1$

2) The derivative in terms of $x$ is at least continuous by part in terms of $t$

3) Domination hypothesis:

You can use a majoration of your function independent of x

$$\forall (x,t) \in {[0,+ \infty)}^2 $$

Or just for all a strictly positive ,on those intervals

$$ \forall (x,t) \in [a,+ \infty) \times {[1,+\infty)}  $$

Answer (score 0):

For example you have there :

1) and 2) obvious lets a positive

$$ \forall(x,t) \in [a,+\infty[\times[1,+\infty[, \ |\dfrac{e^{-xt}}{t}|\leq|\dfrac{e^{-at}}{t}| $$

it is integrable over $$ [1,+\infty[  $$

So you won.

Comment: How to find the derivative?

Comment: You differentiate in terms of x under the integral as you justify the hypothesis above.